# Multiple datasets to ExpandoObject

Tags: c#

I'm currently calling a `sproc`. The returned data from the `sproc` I returned a `IDictionary<string, object>` of `ExpandoObject`. This works perfectly fine for one dataset per `sproc`. Now I've come across a `sproc` which returns data in two different tables. When I call my function I only get the data from the first table. So my question is how can I return the data of the next dataset too.

**Note - I do not have the permission to change the sproc**

The code I have so far is:

```
using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   var names = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(reader.GetName).ToList();

    foreach (IDataRecord record in reader as IEnumerable)
    {
       IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
       foreach (var name in names)
         expando[name] = record[name];

       yield return expando; //yield return to keep the reader open
    }
}
```

Comment: I think i've never seen such  a strange usage of reading data from database... Do you even call `reader.Read()`?

Comment: Do you need [SqlDataReader.NextResult](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311274)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the first glance it doesn't look a big deal. Replace the `foreach` with two nested loops using [`Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`NextResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.nextresult(v=vs.110).aspx) methods and change the method return type from `IEnumerable<dynamic>` to `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<dynamic>>` (or `IDictionary<string, object>` instead of `dynamic`).

However, the problem is that `IEnumerable`s are lazily evaluated, and the `DataReader` is a forward only cursor and can be consumed only once.

One solution could be to buffer every result (dataset) in memory (using `List<dynamic>` for instance) before returning it to the caller, but that would kill the benefits of the deferred execution.

Rather than doing the buffering, I would suggest you a different approach - a method returning flat result set of the following type:

```
public struct QueryResult
{
    public readonly int Index;
    public readonly dynamic Data;
    internal QueryResult(int index, dynamic data)
    {
        Index = index;
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

where the `Index` field will contain the result (dataset) index (0, 1, 2 etc). This would keep the benefits of the deferred execution, and let the caller process it using the most appropriate way - for instance using `foreach` loop(s), LINQ `GroupBy`, [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) `GroupAdjacent` etc.

With that design decision the implementation is straightforward:

```
static IEnumerable<QueryResult> GetData(SqlCommand command)
{
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        int index = 0;
        do
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    expando.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader.GetValue(i));
                yield return new QueryResult(index, expando);
            }
            index++;
        }
        while (reader.NextResult());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How would I call the `GetData()` method? currently I have the implementation as `public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetDataFromSproc()` and call it as `IEnumerable<dynamic> dataList = helper.GetDataFromSproc()`

Comment: It depends of what would you do after the call. What would you expect when there are more than one results? Get list of lists, or build separate lists manually or? Give me some use case.

Comment: Currently if there is more than one result then I call it twice and will combine it into one list. Most of the Sproc that return the data will have one set. However there are a few (4-5) the most which have a result set of 2 or more. Hence why I asked the question. And in the razor view I loop over the `List<T>` and do something like `@Html.DisplayName((string)Model[i].SomeValue)`

Comment: Then the above should work. You would call it once and get the combined list by removing the `Index` like `dataList = GetData(cmd).Select(r => r.Data).ToList()`. Or without `cmd` if you create it inside the method. Sounds good? Or change the signature to `IEnumerable<dynamic> GetData(...)` and the `yield` inside to `yield return expando;` as in your original method.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I'm after. When I run your code I get result set but when I loop over them I get an error saying `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'Test 4'` e.g. I have one sproc which returns two resultset first having 3 columns with value `Test 1, Test 2, Test 3` and the next resultset having just 2 columns with value `Test 4, Test 5` it falls over in the loop because it's looking for the value which is only available in the next result set. How do I overcome this problem

Comment: I think that is an issue of the code in the razor view. Once you get a combined list of the two recordsets, the first let say N items will have 3 columns (properties) and the rest - 2 properties. Basically with `dynamic` list every item can have different set of properties. I don't know how you decide inside the view what property to read from the `dynamic` object. You might try casting to `IDictionary<string, object>` and use `Contains(property_name)` to determine if the `Model[I]` has a specific property?

Comment: I'm trying to cast it to `IDictionary<string, object>` as you suggested but I seem to be getting back empty result set :/. Would it be possible if you can provide an example please including the `Contains()`

Comment: I meant to cast each item of the result set, not the result set itself. So instead of `var value = (string)Model[i].SomeValue;` use something like : `var data = Model[i] as IDictionary<string, object>; var value = data.ContainsKey("SomeValue") ? (string)data["SomeValue"] : null;`. But it's really hard to suggest you something concrete w/o having your concrete usage (or intended usage) code. The answer is covering how you can read and return multiple resultsets from sp, I think how you use the result is outside the scope of the OP (or you need to update it with the exact requirements).

Comment: That's all I needed to know. Thank you, it works as expected now. I combine the two list into one and then in the view as you suggested, cast it to `IDictionary<string, object>`. I've put an if condition because I'm showing the data at different parts of the page. Thanks once again

Comment: Cool! Glad that helped resolving the issue.